# Result set returning nil even there is data in database FMDB Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sqlite, fmdb

Hello I am using FMDB into my swift project. I copied my sqite file into documents directory and it success. I can get sqlite file which is copied into documents directory folder. 
I am inserting data into db as this:

```
if db.open() {
    let InsertQry = "insert into profiles (image_url, name,dob,gender) values ('\(imgName)','\(nameTxt.text!)','\(dobTxt.text!)','\(genderTxt.text!)')"
    print("query= \(InsertQry)")
    let result = db.executeUpdate(InsertQry, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
    if !result {
        print(db.lastErrorMessage())
    }
    else
    {
         print("Success")
    }
 }
```

And it insert data successfully I can see data in sqlite file using sqlite manager(Firefox Add-One plugin).
Now I want to get all data from my table using this code:

```
if db.open() {
    let querySQL = "SELECT * FROM profiles"

    let results:FMResultSet? = self.db.executeQuery(querySQL,withArgumentsInArray: nil)
    if results?.next() == true {
       self.userProfilesArray = NSMutableArray()
       while results!.next() {
            let profileInfo = NSMutableDictionary()
           profileInfo.setObject(results!.stringForColumn("image_url"), forKey: "image_url")
            profileInfo.setObject(results!.stringForColumn("name"), forKey: "name")
            profileInfo.setObject(results!.stringForColumn("dob"), forKey: "dob")
            profileInfo.setObject(results!.stringForColumn("gender"), forKey: "gender")
            self.userProfilesArray.addObject(profileInfo) 
        }
     } else {
         print("results nil")
      }
    db.close()
}
```

Issue is I am going into `if results?.next() == true` statement but I am not going to while loop and I am not getting data even there is data in my databse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to next() consumes a row. If your table contains a single row, your while loop won't see it because the if statement consumes it.

So replace `if results?.next() == true {` with `if let results = results {`. This will even turn the `print("results nil")` line into an accurate line.

After you have ported your existing Objective-C code to Swift, consider using a real Swift SQLite library: they expose result sets as regular collection, handle errors in the Swift way, and are much easier to use. See for example https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift#fetching-rows